# Snare and Tanner Honeypot setup. Syntax error with clone.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, honeypot, snare

Attempting a setup of the Honeypot Snare here and getting an error of sorts.
Installed onto Ubuntu.14 variant, following setups from the github: https://github.com/mushorg/snare

Onto step 3 as it asks: Clone a page: sudo python3 clone.py --target http://example.com

When I try this command on any domain i get the same error. Even with no domain. Seems to be an error with the python code, had a look and can see the def line it points too but that kind of code is through the whole clone.py file.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujlKV.png)

Not sure whats causing it or what ive done wrong if anything. Starting to get into the use of Linux but would still consider myself a beginner.

Any help would be awesome! Thanks!

Comment: Update your Python.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I thought it had to be a specific version for this to work? How would you update python?  and to what version? Thanks! :)

Comment: Also, what pointed you towards that thought? I would like to learn from the experience so whatever made you think this would be appreciated also! :) live and learn!

Comment: [`async` is 3.5+.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/) It looks like they didn't think about version support when they changed their code to use `async`; they still say "tested primarily with >=3.4".

Comment: Thanks for the reply, attempted this with both 3.4 and 3.5 to be sure and still getting the same error. Any other advice?

Answer (score 0):

Updating to a newer OS version .16 worked with all the same commands previously used. Posting to let others know if they experience this! :D